# How does the efficiency curve of a well pump shift with speed?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, motors, pumps, energy-efficiency

Well pump manufacturers publish "efficiency curves" for well pumps, such as this one (the curve that is most sharply convex down, whose Y axis is read from the "% EFF" scale on the right hand side):

[image: Example efficiency curve]

The well pumps are usually sold with a name that reflects the flow rate that yields peak efficiency. So this one is called a "33GS" because it is most efficient at 33 GPM.

These pump curves typically presume a motor speed of 3450 RPM. How might I expect the curve to shift or stretch if the motor speed changes? I'm particularly interested in the range from about 2800 RPM to 3600 RPM.

Comment: 33GS is a range of pumps suitable for different heads  with motors varying from 1 to 10 HP. Each pump having a different Curve

Comment: The % efficiency of the pump head itself is shown as a function of flow rate. There is one % efficiency curve shown for each pump head, regardless of the attached motor. A similar curve—based only on the pump head, independent of the HP of the motor—is shown is other product literature.

Comment: I don't think it's a straightforward question, so I'd recommend you call a Goulds distributor with your question.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into this right now, I don't see a straightforward way to solve this  via pump affinity laws, maybe you can go via the specific speed of the pumpe - However I think the best course of action would be to get the data from the manufacturer.

Comment: Are the impellers of all the pumps in the 33GS series mutually geometrically similar?  And if so, does each pump in the series have a different impeller diameter?

Comment: Get yourself a B+G system sizer circular sliderule and the world of pumping, flowrates, differential pressure, head, suction, and all relevant variable items, including speed curves, piping friction and more is at your fingertips.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to answer your question as you are missing a vital component. "Head"

The flow rate depends on the head as well as the speed of the pump. So it **will have a given flow rate at a certain speed and head.**

Comment: However disregarding your reference to efficiency curves, if I was to assume you actually had 33gpm discharge at 3450 rpm then reducing speed to 2800 would deliver approximately 26.8gpm and 34.4gpm for 3600 rpm

Comment: Use https://theengineeringmindset.com/pump-calculations/ for rule of thumb calculations. These will not give you exact results like working from curves (if you have all the values) will, but I would think that they will be close enough for your use.

Comment: I am not asking how much flow I will get. I am asking how the efficiency curve, which shows energy efficiency of the pump as a function of flow rate, changes with motor speed.